# Migrating data format in Drive Realtime API

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

We have been successfully using the Realtime API in production for a few months, and now we want to change file formats. Our initial file format was, for example,

```
{ 
    version: 1, 
    originalKey: customCollaborativeObject 
}
```

and now we want to update our file format to

```
{ 
    version: 2, 
    newKey: differentCustomCollaborativeObject 
}
```

This is a difficult challenge because we don't have access to the files until users open them.  To make matters worse, a user may simultaneously have two versions of our code open at the same time.

Does the Google Realtime team, or anyone else, have any best practices published for a change in format like this?

Comment: I'm not sure about best practice, but we store a document version on the root of the doc and migrate the entire doc. Clients that load the doc check the version during load to ensure they have been updated correctly. To notify multiple clients we attach a listener to the version field in the realtime doc. The handler will disconnect other clients, both from the same user or other users, from the document until the clients have been updated. Once the migration is done, we reload the page so the user cannot undo the migration.

Comment: Ok, that's just about what we have in mind too. Thanks!